# Program to print Factorial of a number in c++

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, logic

Q) Write a program that defines and tests a factorial function. The factorial of a number is the product of all whole numbers from 1 to N.
For example, the factorial of 5 is 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120

Problem: I am able to print the result,but not able to print like this :

```
let n = 5
Output : 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120;
```

My Code:

```
# include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


int Factorial (int N)
{
    int i = 0;int fact = 1;

    while (i < N && N > 0) // Time Complexity O(N)
    {
        fact *=  ++i;
    }

    return fact;
}

int main()
  {
    int n;cin >> n;
    
    cout << Factorial(n) << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You can use a stringstream and a for loop to generate a string like "x * x+1 * x+2 ..." and concatenate it with another generic string "Factorial of x ..." before you cout << Factorial(n) << endl

Comment: I've seen you edited your question. Do you still need help? If not it would be nice if you mark the question as solved.

Comment: Thanks, @AidenDean for your help. I've marked the qn as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to print the result,but not able to print like this : let n
> = 5 Output : 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120;

That's indeed what your code is doing. You only print the result.
If you want to print every integer from 1 to N before you print the result you need more cout calls or another way to manipulate the output.

This should only be an idea this is far away from being a good example but it should do the job.

```
int main()
  {
    int n;cin >> n;
    
    std::cout << "Factorial of " << n << "!\n";
    for (int i =1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(i != n)
            std::cout << i << " * ";
        else
            std::cout << n << " = ";
    }

    cout << Factorial(n) << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Better approach using [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    stringstream sStr;
    sStr << "Factorial of " << n << " = ";
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i != n)
            sStr << i << " * ";
        else
            sStr << i << " = ";
    }
    sStr << Factorial(n) << endl;
    cout << sStr.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is it better to use a `stringstream` rather than printing directly?

Comment: Why is it better approach to use `stringstream`? rather than printing directly.